# Parsing comlpex JSON with SwiftyJSON

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I am trying again and again to parse the thumbnail path address from this JSON

```
"data":{ 
        "offset":0,
        "limit":20,
        "total":1491,
        "count":20,
        "results":[  
            {  
                "id":1011334,
                "name":"3-D Man",
                "description":"",
                "modified":"2014-04-29T14:18:17-0400",
                "thumbnail":{  
                    "path":"http://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/c/e0/535fecbbb9784",
                    "extension":"jpg"
                },
```

But I can't seem to have found the answer to my question. I am doing this:

```
 for (key, subJson) in json["data", "results", "thumbnail", "path"] {
                    if let imagePath = subJson["path"].string {
                        print(imagePath)
                        let finalImagePath = imagePath + "somestring with my priv key and pub key"
                        print(finalImagePath)
                    }
                }
```

I have done this to pare the name and id for the characters like this:

```
for (key, subJson) in json["data"]["results"] {
                    if let name = subJson["name"].string, let id = subJson["id"].int {
                        cardInfo.append(CardInfo(id: id, name: name))
//                        print(cardInfo)
                    }
                }
```

and it works just perfect, but in the case of the thumbnail I have been stuck for a while searching online and trying to figure it out by myself

I would much appreciate if someone give me the answer to this, I have been struggling for so long now.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
if let item = json["data"]["results"].array?.first , let path = item["thumbnail"]["path"].string  { 
   print(path) 
}
```

---

For All

```
for (_, subJson) in json["data"]["results"] {
   if let path = subJson["thumbnail"]["path"].string {
      print(path) 
   }
}
```